# How to log in masstransit?

Tags: nlog, masstransit

I made a lot of research (at oficial documentation, github's issues page and stackoverflow) about how to log data in masstransit (remembering that log features is decoupled from any log implementation) and even on masstransit's github famous samples as *Sample-ShoppingWeb*, *Sample-Booking* and *Starbucks* i could not understand how to log data on application...

I installed **MassTransit.NLog** and configured my bus as bellow:

```
var bus = BusConfigurator.ConfigureBus((cfg, host) =>
{
    ...
    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, RabbitMqConstants.SagaQueue, e =>
    {
        cfg.UseNLog();
...
```

...and giving a look at the NLog tutorial https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial i installed the package *NLog.Config* (that have the nuget dependencies *NLog* and *NLog.Schema*)
and was added on my project the files *NLog.config* and**NLog.xsd*...
...
The problem isn't on NLog itself, but i can´t understand how to log information on masstransit...

On my OrderStateMachine class i do the following

```
...
Initially(
When(RegisterOrder)
    .Then(context =>
    {
        var log = Logger.Get("logfile");
        log.Info(context);
        log.InfoFormat("Register Order {0}", "register");
        throw new ArgumentException("Test for monitoring sagas");
        log.Error(context);
        //throw new ArgumentException("Test for monitoring sagas");
...
```

I don´t know even which class and methods should i use (on masstransit)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood, just pass as an argument a NLog factory instance as follows: `cfg.UseNLog(new LogFactory());` with this the `Logger.Get("logfile");` returns an Masstransit's abstraction class (wich methods should be called according with log level  desired)...

Great abstraction, so simple and so cool!

Comment: This is now deprecated: https://masstransit.io/support/upgrade#logging